# configure scheduler with weblogic server to save some reports in excel format using java

Tags: weblogic

I want to configure scheduler with weblogic server to save some reports in excel format using java.

Can anybody help with the code and steps to achieve this as i new to weblogic

Answer (score 0):

Java scheduler is not really WLS specific. There are frameworks such as [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) that are application server agnostic. You can check out the [quartz code sample](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/07/quartz-2-scheduler-example.html) here or google yourself. You can also use the [Timer Service](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html) feature in the EJB3 if you prefer.